# Not able to configure OTP using Twilio

Tags: java, twilio, one-time-password, twilio-api

Not able to configure Twilio for OTP of my app. No help from Twilio as they want us to buy a minimum $500 support plan whichis huge for a small startup. Stuck badly. Purchased 20$ credit and bought the Number for 1$ but no help.

Please note that thier URL for the help page is also of no use. Can someone guide us to a setp by setp process for the same and can someone also suggest should we use Programmable SMS or Authy. 
Authy is for 2FA?

Comment: What do you mean by OTP? You don't say what you have tried, can you give more details about what exactly are you trying to do? What URL is of no use? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

If you are looking at implementing multi-factor authentication in Java I'd suggest having a look at this Authy tutorial:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/account-verification/java/servlets

If you simply want to send SMS messages, here is the SMS Quickstart for SMS:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/java/sms

As Alex said, if let us know what you've tried already and what errors or incorrect behavior you've encountered we can provide much more detailed guidance.

Hope that helps.